# Dynamic content share on social network

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dns, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am implementing single page online deals website in java script, jsp's and java, in this page there are multiple products or deals and each deal will have image, url, description and share button. I have defined meta tags in order to share on social media, when user chooses the deal/product and clicks on corresponding share button, I am updating meta tags values with corresponding product image, url and description in javascript. But this is not working, Facebook always sharing the data defined in originally defined meta tags values not updated meta tags values. how to do to read the updated or real time meta tags values by social media.?

Comment: The URL you share needs to contain the OG-tags you want. Facebook will not get the OG tags from the page of the share button. It will scrape the URL you share and get the OG tags from that

Comment: Thank you Wizkid for quick response, yes I have OG tags like below

Comment: Thank you Wizkid for quick response, yes I have OG tags like below: <!-- Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
...
....

<meta property="og:price:currency" content="USD" />  but I am changing OG tag values when user clicks on share button for each deal in javascript but its not working, each deal will have unique URL and I can not use same URL for all deals. is there any way to achive this.? dealnews.com can able to share image, desc, url dynamically for each deal.? how to achieve this.? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you read what I said? Facebook doesn't use the og tags from the page you share from. We go and scrape the URL that you shared.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. Its my bad I confused. Lets say I have my application domain www.example.com and in this application I have multiple products or deals and each deal/product contains the share button with url's like this www.example.com?prodid=1, www.example.com?prodid=2 etc. Now when I share on FB, its scraping the URL that was defined for www.example.com. now how to tell FB to scrape the data for www.example.com?prodid=1 when user clicks on share button of product 1. I am a Java developer and new to web development, that would be great if you elaborate with more details.

Comment: If your share button shares  www.example.com?prodid=1 Facebook will then scrape that URL and get the OG tags from the HTML you return when Facebook scrape the URL.

Comment: Thank you Wizkid, I found out how to do facebook scrape with open graph api to read meta tags when user clicks on share button, now my requirement is I have to change the meta tag values in html head section when user clicks on share button, I am updating meta tag values in java script but FB is not reading updated meta tag values in java script. I have to update meta tag values in html head section. App built in JSP and Java. Is there any way to update html meta tag values dynamically.

Comment: Just share a unique URL and when Facebook scrape that URL you populate the og tags with the correct values

Comment: Thank you. My issue is resolved. When user clicking on share buttion, I am generating unique url and making rest api call to facebook to scrape the url. Once again Thank you Wizkid.

Comment: Hi Wizkid, I got another problem. Actually I created the domain in godaddy and forwarding request to hosting server, for instace hosting server url http://example-test.rhcloud.com/allProudcts?prodId=25, facebook scraping correctly for this url but I created the domain in godaddy and forwarding to above url , sharing with domin url for instance http://example.com/allProducts?prodId=25 is not scraping correct title, image, description etc, facebook scraping default values from godaddy not from hosting server. How to resolve this issue.?

Comment: What URL are you actually sharing? Have you checked the debugger?

Comment: I am sharing this URL: http://deemdeal.in/allDeals?dealId=25, I checked the debugger, its reading default values from domain but if I share hosting server URL http://deemdeal-yallamraju.rhcloud.com/allDeals?dealId=25 it reads correctly.

Comment: I checked the view page source on domain and I see the below code, <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>deemdeal.in</title>
  
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://deemdeal-yallamraju.rhcloud.com" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
</html>, How to fix this, hosting server url sharing working properly but URL looks ugly, I want to use domain name to share on social media but meta tags are bad. how to fix this.

Comment: You change the domain to point to your server instead of using an iframe

Comment: You are awesome, Thank you again.  It resolved after pointing server ip in domain settings. Thank You.

Comment: I see facebook provides product meta tags and I additionally added the below tags <meta property="product:original_price:amount" content="500.0" /> Meta Tag <meta property="product:original_price:currency" content="INR" /> Meta Tag <meta property="product:sale_price:amount" content="100.0" /> Meta Tag <meta property="product:sale_price:currency" content="INR" /> but facebook not showing these data when I share but facebook share debugger shows these tags with no warnings. is there any additional setup to work.?  deemdeal.in/allDeals?dealId=31

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you.

For Facebook share button, visit [Facebook Developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) Page.

[image: Screenshot from FB Dev Page]

**Include this code ideally right after the opening body tag.**

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v11.0&appId=538207386357467&autoLogAppEvents=1" nonce="24Yn8yJY"></script>
```

**Add this snippet anywhere you want the button  to appear**

```html
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://place-your shareable-url-here" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
```

In my case i'm using PHP
so i put this in my `data-href = "<php echo '$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]' ?>"`

Source : [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button)